# C - Pass and operate on char pointers and pointer-to-pointer

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

As a novice to the C language I am fighting with pointers, specially with double pointers.

My intention is to

1. malloc char pointer in `main`
2. pass the malloced pointer to different functions
3. get the result of each function within the same pointer
4. free the pointer in `main`

This is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void process1(char **pointer) {
    //this should take and change the pointer value from a to x
    (*pointer)[0] = 'x';
    (*pointer)[1] = '\0';
}

void process2(char **pointer) {
    //this should take the pointer, free and NULL it, do a new malloc and set the pointer value to y
    char* p = *pointer;
    free(p);
    p = NULL;

    p = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    p[0] = 'y';
    p[1] = '\0';

    *pointer = p;
}

void main() {
    char* p = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    p[0] = 'a';
    p[1] = '\0';
    //should print a
    printf("%s\n",p);
    process1(&p);
    //should print x
    printf("%s\n",p);
    process2(&p);
    //should print y
    printf("%s\n",p);

    free(p);
    p=NULL;

}

//this is the Output as expectd
sh-4.2$ main
a
x
y
```

My questions now are:

1. Is this good practice?
2. Am I leaking memory in the function `process2` when mallocing the `p` pointer? Do I need to free this `p` pointer somewhere?

Comment: Your `process2` is re-allocating and *modifying* a pointer allocated in `main`. I would say this is not a good practice. If you expect a pointer to be allocated and freed by the caller, don't touch it in the function. Especially knowing that this pointer can be actually statically allocated.

Comment: No leaks in `process2`.

Comment: double pointers are just like float pointers, but (usually) the object pointed to is larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program is well-behaving.  It properly frees all allocated memory, and does not write outside the bounds of allocated memory.

What `process2` is doing is fine from the perspective of reallocating previously allocated memory.  In this particular case, you're allocating the same amount of memory as before, but in general if such a function might be expanding allocated memory then it makes sense to pass a double pointer to modify the pointer variable in the calling function.

As for `process1`, the pointer being passed in by address is not being modified, just what it points to, so there's no need for a double pointer here.  You could instead define it as:

```
void process1(char *pointer) {
    pointer[0] = 'x';
    pointer[1] = '\0';
}
```

And call it like this:

```
process1(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is this good practice?

- Dynamical memory is useful when you dont know how many input data you will receive in compile time. You can easily realloc size of dynamical array, while you cant modify size of array on stack.
- Big disadvantages are memory leaks and possible segmentaion faults.
- You have to `free` allocated memory.
- Arrays declared on *automatic storage* are easier to use and faster

There is no need to pass an pointer to pointer in your case, simply use

```
void process1(char *pointer) {
    pointer[0] = 'x';

process1(p);
```

In process2, instead of freeing and allocating new memory, you can use `realloc()`. Lest suggest `pointer` is `char*`.

```
pointer = realloc (pointer, 4 * sizeof(int));
```

- You won't lose data which are already stored in `pointer` array

---

> 2. Am I leaking memory in the function process2 when mallocing the p pointer?

No, there arent any memory leaks or touching outside of bounds.

---

If you are working with pointers, its good practice to debug your programs with tool named [valgrind.](http://valgrind.org/)

If you dont have to use *dynamic allocation*, dont. Its error prone, slower and you have to free data.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not a good idea to free memory in the function unless you are 100% sure that the pointer passed has been malloced. Otherwise it is extremely error prone if you forget about it and pass any other pointer.
2. Your function

> ```
> void process1(char **pointer) {
>     //this should take and change the pointer value from a to x
>     (*pointer)[0] = 'x';
>     (*pointer)[1] = '\0';
> }
> ```

does not need char ** parameter

```
void process1(char *pointer) {
    //this should take and change the pointer value from a to x
    pointer[0] = 'x';   // or *pointer = 'x';          or *pointer++ = 'x';
    pointer[1] = '\0';  // or *(pointer + 1) = '\0';   or *pointer = '\0';
}
```